# How to start development with Sitecore Commerce 9 / Sitecore Commerce 9 Learning Resources

Tags: sitecore-commerce, commerce-engine, commerce-server, commerce-connect, training

I am new to Sitecore Experience Commerce (SXC) 9 development and want to embrace the whole platform.

Where should I start?

What should I learn, watch & read?

Where can I find help if I need it?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**1. Sitecore Commerce Documention**

Great resource is [Sitecore official documentation](https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xc/index.html) which contains:

- Developer's Guide -> http://commercesdn.sitecore.net/SitecoreXC_9.0/Developers-Guide/Sitecore-XC-9.0_Developers_Guide.pdf
- DevOps Guide -> http://commercesdn.sitecore.net/SitecoreXC_9.0/DevOps-Guide/Sitecore-XC-9.0_DevOps_Guide.pdf
- Installation Guide:
- For On-Premises - http://commercesdn.sitecore.net/SitecoreXC_9.0/Installation-Guide/Sitecore-XC-9.0_Installation_Guide(On-Prem).pdf
- for Azure App Service - http://commercesdn.sitecore.net/SitecoreXC_9.0/Installation-Guide/Sitecore-XC-9.0_Installation_Guide(Cloud).pdf
- Business Tools User's Guide:
- http://commercesdn.sitecore.net/SitecoreXC_9.0/Users-Guide/en-us/index.html
- http://tothecore.sk/2018/07/04/sitecore-experience-commerce-9-business-tools-users-guide-for-ereaders
- SXA Storefront Guide:
- https://doc.sitecore.net/sxa_storefront
- http://tothecore.sk/2018/07/09/sitecore-experience-commerce-sxc-9-documentation-for-ereaders/
- Commerce Connect:

1. Developer's Guide - http://commercesdn.sitecore.net/SitecoreXC_9.0/Commerce-Connect/Sitecore_Connect_90_Developer_Guide.pdf
2. Integration Guide - http://commercesdn.sitecore.net/SitecoreXC_9.0/Commerce-Connect/Sitecore_Connect_90_Integration_Guide.pdf
3. Setting up Commerce Connect

- https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_commerce/setting_up_commerce_connect
- http://tothecore.sk/2018/07/09/sitecore-experience-commerce-sxc-9-documentation-for-ereaders/

4. Commerce Connect Components:

- https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_commerce/commerce_connect_components
- http://tothecore.sk/2018/07/09/sitecore-experience-commerce-sxc-9-documentation-for-ereaders/

5. Reports:

- https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_commerce/reports
- http://tothecore.sk/2018/07/09/sitecore-experience-commerce-sxc-9-documentation-for-ereaders/

**2. Youtube**

When you like to see things in action and narrated - take a look on two Youtube playlists that are part of [Master Sitecore channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/mastersitecore/playlists) which is maintained by Sitecore itself and I definitely recommend to watch all "episodes".

List of Commerce related playlists on [Master Sitecore channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/mastersitecore/playlists):

- ["Sitecore Commerce Deep Dive"](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL1jJVFm_lGny-vqNPTv3VdBA_o31-Tq94) - Content more oriented for developers describing how Commerce Engine and all other parts of SXC work internally
- ["Sitecore Experience Commerce"](https://m.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL1jJVFm_lGnwa9R0XqeGrhmNj1AHbAnE9) - Content more oriented for merchandisers and other users of SXC with lot of how to videos

Lot's of great non-commerce recordings regarding [architecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EzfV6RjCD8A&list=PL1jJVFm_lGnzMUBFF_IX5q0o-3UOX2mIs), [Helix](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL1jJVFm_lGnz0XzXU5uNJSgTGMxNFsOky), [xConnect](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL1jJVFm_lGnxaNZ6AUm_GQNOxFHOjZAGp) and many more can be found there also. Just [check it out](https://www.youtube.com/user/mastersitecore/playlists), you won't regret!

**3. Sitecore Official Commerce Trainings / Exams**

- *Online Trainings*

I have learnt a lot taking and passing online trainings:

- [Commerce Foundations 9 Collection](https://learning.sitecore.com/user/consume/learning_pathway/5d48cb92-0c3b-3fa1-9683-482dc020fae0/25)
- [Commerce Developer's Fundamentals 9 Collection](https://learning.sitecore.com/user/consume/learning_pathway/5d48cb92-0c3b-3fa1-9683-482dc020fae0/26)
- Take a look [on my humble review](http://tothecore.sk/2018/06/25/sitecore-commerce-9-100-overview-and-200-essentials-trainings-developer-view/) of these two official trainings from Sitecore. Will get you definitely up to speed!
- *Onsite Training*

There is also more advanced onsite training:

- [Sitecore Experience Commerce 9.0 300: Advanced](https://www.sitecore.com/services-and-support/training/classroom-training/back-end-developers/sitecore-commerce-for-developers?sc_lang=en&retrofit=1)
- *Commerce Essentials Exam*

You can also test your knowledge by passing Sitecore Experience Commerce (SXC) 9 Essentials Certification:

- [Official Study guide](https://sitecore.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/16000077959-sitecore-experience-commerce-9-0-essentials-certification-developer-exam-study-guide) - You will learn here exactly how to register for this exam, details about exam and topics you need to cover during your preparation.
- [Study guide](http://tothecore.sk/2018/07/16/sitecore-experience-commerce-sxc-9-essentials-certification-study-guide) prepared by [Peter Prochazka](https://tothecore.sk/) - You will know exactly what steps you need to do in order to successfully pass this exam with all links to documentation and suggestion how to embrace preparation for this exam.

**4. Blogs**

There are lots of Sitecore developers who share their knowledge, expertise and experience through their blogs, youtube channels and so on. Some are specialized in Sitecore Commerce particularly. This can be great source of truth and could help you find solution to your problems pretty quickly because you know, there is big probability that somebody experienced same problems as you before or somebody already developed similar solution to your current requirements ;) Also wise people learn by other's faults ;)

- Some notable Sitecore Commerce bloggers you should follow (some are also [Sitecore Commerce MVPs](https://mvp.sitecore.net/)):
- https://blog.ryanbailey.co.nz/
- https://blog.richardszalay.com/
- https://hachweb.wordpress.com/
- https://tothecore.sk/tag/sitecore-commerce-9/
- http://andrewsutherland.azurewebsites.net/blog/
- https://medium.com/redhotminute-australia
- https://websterian.com/
- https://naveed-ahmad.com/
- https://buoctrenmay.com/
- http://www.sitecorecpok.com/
- https://himadritechblog.wordpress.com/
- https://davehetal.wordpress.com/category/sitecore/commerce/
- https://sitecoredude.com/

**5. Twitter**

If you are on twitter, you can follow [@commerceminion](https://twitter.com/commerceminion). It is a bot automatically retweeting all Sitecore Commerce related tweets. Great source of knowledge if you want to stay up to date!

**6. Help**

If you are seeking help, you can use lot's of channels:

- Sitecore Stack Exchange - https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sitecore-commerce
- Sitecore Slack Channel - https://sitecorechat.slack.com/ (join #ecommerce channel) - read [here how to join](https://www.akshaysura.com/2015/10/27/how-to-join-sitecore-slack-community-chat/)
- Sitecore Commerce Community / Forums - https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/6
- Sitecore Support - https://support.sitecore.net/helpdesk/

**7. Sitecore Habitat Home Commerce demo**

Great source of knowledge and help in the beginning of your Sitecore Commerce journey can be also Sitecore Habitat Home Commerce demo. This is demo / code repository of Sitecore Commerce solution and can used as a reference and inspiration for your solution.

More information about Sitecore Habitat Home Commerce demo:

- Source codes and instructions can be found here - https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore.HabitatHome.Commerce
- Detailed step-by-step installation guide was written by Viet Hoang - https://buoctrenmay.com/2018/06/01/sitecore-demo-habitat-home-commerce-step-by-step-setup-guide/
- Join #habitathome channel in Sitecore Slack